# How to create div in jQuery from a JSON answer for showing data?

Tags: jquery, html, json

lets say Im requesting (ajax) for some records, which returns:

```
[
  [ID: 1, name: 'fdssdfdsf'],
  [ID: 2, name: 'vxcvxcvxcv'],
  [ID: 3, name: '333333']
]
```

and it should be displayed:

```
try
{
    answer = $.parseJSON(answer);
    targetDiv.html('');
    for(var record in answer)
    {
        record = answer[record];

        /////////////
    }
}
catch(e)
{
    alert('Server is down!');
}
```

and now I can see two ways:

doing by creating DOM-s:

```
var cloneFrom = $('<div>');
cloneFrom.addClass('container');
cloneFrom.append($('<div>').addClass('date').text(record.post_title));

targetDiv.append(cloneFrom);
```

OR creating "raw"

```
var s = '';
s+= '<div>'+record.post_title+'</div>';
```

which one could be the best? 2nd seems easier

Comment: Your response data format is invalid, arrays cannot contain keys in Js

Comment: Why cant you return your AJAX response as JSON instead of parsing the response when it comes back? Rory is correct, arrays cannot contain keys in JS, but this is one of the main advantages of JSON